# VS Code: divide Python code block into regions - how to mark regions?

Tags: python, formatting, visual-studio-code

How to apply regions for python code in Visual Studio Code?

I would like to do this like in VS C#:

```
#region
// some methods
#endregion
```

Comment: TL;DR : go to the line with the `def` keyword and hit `Ctrl+Shift+[`

Comment: I need to know how to decorate code block so it can be Ctrl+Shift+[ to hide

Comment: ok, shame on me. the answer is simple: text between region marks needs to be intended